# Select an item in an autocomplete dropdown in html using vba

Tags: html, vba

I am currently working on web scraping and I encounter an issue with choosing a specific item in `<li>` tag dropdown. Below is VBA code to select:

```
drop_down = iedoc.getElementById(ui-id-2).getElementsByTagName("li")

    For Each Name In drop_down       ' loop all options of drop down menu
        str = Mid(Name.innerText, Len(Name.innerText) - 4, 3)
        If StrComp(iata, str, 1) = 0 Then      'these two lines are used to match what i want (iata) and what is given in the list (str)
           Name.Click
```

Everything works well except it always clicks the first item in the dropdown, below is html element for reference:

```
<ul tabindex="0" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-2" style="left: 1437px; top: 223.14px; width: 280px; display: none;">
<li tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-178">HELSINKI,FINL                                              (HEL       )</li>
<li tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-179">SINGAPORE,SING                                              (SIN       )</li></ul>
</ul>
```

Let's say I want to select "Singapore...", however my current vba can only select "HELSINKI...". And I am sure that both the For loop and the if statement work fine.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Is there a public url that can be used for testing? Your id is also missing the "" and what is an example value for _iata_ ?

Comment: Here's the website: https://www.icao.int/environmental-protection/Carbonoffset/Pages/default.aspx;  and example can be HKG to SIN

Answer (score 0):

If you know the airport code seems you can do something like

```
ie.document.querySelector(".to1").value = "SIN"
```

and

```
ie.document.querySelector(".frm1").value = 'HKG'
```

May need to execute via javascript.